# my media query in CSS is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm using a simple code and the media query at 991 is not working properly, it's like 991px is not inclusive which is not supposed to be the case, here's my code , any help?

```css
/* On screens that are 992px wide or more, the background color is blue */
    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
      body {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
      body {
        background-color: olive;
        color: white;
      }
    }
```

```html
    
    <h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
    <p>By default, the background color of the document is "tan". If the screen size is 992px or more, the color will change to "blue". If it is 991px or less, it will change to "olive".</p>
```

Comment: it's giving me a blank layout

Comment: add meta: <meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"> in head tag

Comment: I'd remove the media query for your blue and white template make that your default state then you only have to worry about your max-width for the olive and white template

Comment: i used the code in code pen and it run fine... olive to blue..  maybe use !imporant at the end of the styles

Answer (score 1):

The width of screen or any HTML elements can have floating values for their width, like `width: 991.2px;`. When you define rules for screen with less width than 991px and more width than 992px, you let a *no-rule zone* exist between 991px and 992px. I think we can't have a solution without this *no-rule zone*, but we can reduce his size.

Working example :

```css
/* On screens that are 992px wide or more, the background color is blue */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}/* On screens that are 991.999px wide or less, the background color is olive */
@media (max-width: 991.999px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
    color: white;
  }
}
/* On screens that are between 991.999px and 992px wide, no background color is assign */
```

```html
<h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
<p>By default, the background color of the document is "tan". If the screen size is 992px or more, the color will change to "blue". If it is 991.999px or less, it will change to "olive".</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the max-width media query at all, set the body color to olive by default and then add the min-width for anything over 992px.

```css
/* On screens that are 992px wide or more, the background color is blue */
    
    body {
        background-color: olive;
        color: white;
      }

    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
      body {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
      }
    }
```

```html
    
    <h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
    <p>By default, the background color of the document is "tan". If the screen size is 992px or more, the color will change to "blue". If it is 991px or less, it will change to "olive".</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should do is to a small change to your `@media`  make the `min-width` to works from `992px` and above and your `max-width` to work from `992px` and `below` the min-width media will kick off at the `991px`. And the blue background now works from 992px and above.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Width a screen of `width: 992px;` exactly, both styles will apply. Here you have the same properties define in both @media, but in case you define some properties only in one of the @media : You will have different styles for screen less than, exactly, and wider than 992px.

Comment: Works fine to me.

Comment: Reformulate : When you have the exact same properties defined in both media, it will works fine (as it is here). You will have both styles apply on the exact width (here 992px), and it could be problematic with properties NOT defined in both media